# string comparison in a while loop

Tags: python

I've written a small piece of code that should detect if there are any matching characters in the same place in the 2 strings. If there is , the score in incremented by 1, if there is 2 or more consecutive matching characters , the score is incremented by 3, if there is no matching character, the score is decremented by 1.
The problem is though , when i try to run the code, it gives me a error: string index out of range. 
What might be wrong ? thank you very much.

```
def pairwiseScore(seqA, seqB):
    count = 0
    score = 0
    while count < len(seqA):
        if seqA[count] == seqB[count]:
            score = score + 1
            count = count + 1
            while seqA[count] == seqB[count]:  # This is the line the error occurs
                score = score + 3
                count = count + 1 
        elif seqA[count] != seqB[count]:
            score = score - 1
            count = count + 1
    return score
```

Comment: "What might be wrong?" you said it yourself "string index out of range". Don't get me wrong I understand it's homework but google is your friend and this is the time to get your debugging skills up and running

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the meaning of this error. From what i understand, it means that if a string is 8 characters long, and the index is [8], the error occurs. But, in my code, the index isn't longer than the lenght of the string.

Comment: @geekkid: see my answer. You ARE indexing past the length of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes are numberd 0 to n.

```
len(someString)
```

will give you n + 1.

Let's say that your string is length 10, and the indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Your while loop checks the condition that count is < 10. So far so good.

Ok now let's say that count is equal to 9. Immediately within the first while loop, you increment count.

So now count = 10.

Now attempting to access someString[count] will give you an `IndexError` because the indices only go up to 9.

Answer (score 1):

Do both strings have the same lenght? otherwise you should consider using something like:

`while count < min(len(seqA), len(seqB)):`

Comment: yes, both of the strings should have the same lenght. But non the less, thank you for your remark, as i didn't even know the min function exists :D .

Answer (score 1):

Also, the `zip` function might come in handy here to pair off the letters in each word. It is a [python builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip). e.g.

```
def letter_score(s1, s2):
    score = 0
    previous_match = False

    z = zip(s1, s2)
    for pair in z:
        if pair[0] == pair[1]:
            if previous_match:
                score += 3
            else:
                score += 1
                previous_match = True
        else:
            score -= 1
            previous_match = False
    return score
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it: You're trying to access a character beyond the boundaries of your string. Consider this:

```
>>> s = "hello"
>>> len(s)
5
>>> s[4]
'o'
```

Now when (at the start of the first `while` loop) `count` is 1 below `len(seqA)`, then you're incrementing `count` and then you're doing `seqA[count]` which will throw this exception.

Let's assume you're calling `pairwisescore("a", "a")`:

```
score = 0
count = 0
while count < len(seqA):                   # 0 < 1 --> OK 
    if seqA[count] == seqB[count]:         # "a" == "a" --> OK
        score = score + 1                  # score = 1
        count = count + 1                  # count = 1
        while seqA[count] == seqB[count]:  # seqA[1] doesn't exist!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pairwiseScore(seqA, seqB):
    count = 0
    score = 0
    isOne = False
    isTwoOrMore = False
    while count < min(len(seqA), len(seqB)):
        if seqA[count] == seqB[count]:
            if isTwoOrMore:
                score = score + 3
                count = count + 1
            else:
                if isOne:
                    isTwoOrMore = True
                score = score + 1
                count = count + 1
                isOne = True
        elif seqA[count] != seqB[count]:
            score = score - 1
            count = count + 1
            isOne = False
            isTwoOrMore = False
    return score

a = 'apple'
b = 'aplle'
print(pairwiseScore(a, b))
```

I think this one solve the problem, I added a "counting" `bool` variable. And to respond to the question, your program didn't compare the length of the second string.

```
while count < min(len(seqA), len(seqB)):
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second while loop you must test that count is less than len(seqA):

```
while count < len(seqA) and seqA[count] == seqB[count]:
   ...
```

and, also there's possibly other bug: If the length of seqB is less than length of seqA, you'll again see runtime exception. so, you should change every occurence of `count < len(seqA)` with `count < min(len(seqA), len(seqB))`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do this:

```
    count = count + 1
```

Both before the inner `while` loop and at the end of it. But you then continue using `seqA[count]` before checking it against `len(seqA)` again - so, once it goes too high, Python will try to read past the end of `seqA`, and you'll get that error (when, if the condition had been checked again after incrementing, the loop would have ended).

Using a Python `for` loop will get around bugs like this, since Python will manage `count` for you:

```
for a,b in zip(seqA, seqB):
     if a == b:
        score += 1
```

You can implement the extra-points bit easily in this by keeping track of whether the *previous* character is a match, rather than trying to work out how many *after* this one are. A boolean variable `last_matched` that you keep updated would help with this.